# Counting the number of minimal covers of a binary matrix

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Given a binary $n$-times-$n$ matrix $A$, we'd like to cover the regions comprised of $1$'s with non-intersecting rectangles. A collection of disjoint rectangles that covers all $1$'s (and only $1$'s, i.e., it mustn't cover any $0$'s) is called a *cover*. (Notice that a problem instance may have *many* different covers.)

A cover is called a *minimum cover* if it uses the smallest number of rectnagles possible.

The counting problem I'm interested in is: given an $n$-times-$n$ binary matrix $A$, count the number of minimum covers of $A$.

What can you say about this problem? (This post was inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870384/algorithms-how-to-highlight-image-difference-using-rectangles).)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: "What can you say about X?" is too broad a query. Please narrow down your question.

Comment: Hi, well, it is not an assignment or anything like that. I'm a software engineer with an active interest in the rather academic subjects of algorithms and computational complexity. Browsing the stackoverflow this question caught my attention and I thought that maybe it's a well-studied problem (perhaps bounds on the number of possible rectangles are known; which complexity classes it belongs to; maybe it has a really nice algorithm; etc. etc.)

Comment: Okay, but you still need to narrow it down. And every properly scoped question, e.g. "Is this problem in class X?" would then prompt my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show that some inputs can produce an exponential number of minimum covers.  Consider the following 3x3 matrix:

```
110
100
000
```

This can be minimally covered in exactly 2 ways: either using a single vertical 2x1 rectangle and a single 1x1 rectangle, or a single horizontal 1x2 rectangle and a single 1x1 rectangle.

Thus placing $k$ non-overlapping copies of this gadget in a grid will produce an instance with $2^k$ distinct minimal covers.  You could, for example, tile an $n$ by $n$ grid with $n^2/9$ of them to produce an instance with $2^{n^2/9}$ minimal covers.

(It's possible that a better gadget exists -- that is, smaller gadgets that would increase the coefficient in the exponent.  More interestingly it's possible that instances with *asymptotically more* minimal covers exist.)

Comment: This only works when we are talking about a contiguous rectangle, and not a *combinatorial rectangle*, i.e. a set $R \subset X \times Y$ so that $(x, y) \in R$ and $ (x', y') \in R \implies (x, y') \in R$. If we allow them to be combinatorial rectangles, then I believe there are still just $2$ choices no matter what $n$ is in this construction.

Comment: @MCT: I think that's an interesting question, though in general there are still inputs that need an exponential number of combinatorial rectangles: instead of placing copies of my gadget in a grid, place $k$ copies of it along a diagonal line.  No combinatorial rectangle can cover cells in 2 different gadgets, because their "opposite corners" will be 0-cells, so you need $k$ separate pairs of combinatorial rectangles, one pair per gadget.  As before, each gadget can be covered independently in 2 different ways, for $2^k$ different solutions overall.

Answer (score 2):

This problem comes up as a technique for proving lower bounds in communication complexity. See for example [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos598B/commcomplexity1.pdf).

There are some bounds on the number of rectangles. For example the number of rectangles is at least the rank of the matrix. Google yields more with the search terms "monochromatic rectangle tiling".